# Replacing layer ArcSDE connection

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, layers

I am very new to using Python...

I have an MXD with all of my layer files in it. They are grouped by category etc. Each layer file references a dataset within my SDE. My SDE has two different connections, Admin and View. Admin allows administration of all feature classes. View is a select only connection.

All of my layers should be connected to feature classes in the View SDE connection. However I have over 70 layers which reference the Admin SDE connection. How do I change this using Python. I do not want to manually change the source SDE connection and then save a new layer.

Would it also be possible to overwrite the layer file using its current file information and location?

I have tried the following bits of code but no luck...

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
     lyr.replaceDataSource(r"C:\Users\x939062\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\MMO_View.sde", "SDE_WORKSPACE",,"False")
```

I have also tried the following, but again no luck...

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    lyr.findandreplaceworkspacepath (r"C:\Users\x939062\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\MMO_Admin.sde", r"C:\Users\x939062\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\MMO_View.sde")
```

Comment: Also, I should have made it clearer in my question, but the layer files im refereing to are lyr files within my mxd. They reference feature classes within my SDE connection. I have two different connections with different privliedge rights, admin and view. I need to make sure the lyr files reference the view sde connection rathat than the admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was just doing this yesterday. You should just be able to call `findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths` on your `mxd` object. Below will loop through the dict objects in the `workspacePathMap` array and replace old with new:

```
mxdFn = r"C:\path\to\original\mxd.mxd"
newMxdFn = r"C:\path\to\new\mxd.mxd"

workspacePathMap = [{
    "old": r'C:\path\to\old\conn.sde',
    "new": r'C:\path\to\new\conn.sde'
    },
    {
    "old": r'D:\old-dir',  # shp, fgdb
    "new": r'D:\new--dir'
    }]

def updateDataSources(mxdFn, workspacePathMap, newMxdFn):
    print "Repathing {0}".format(mxdFn)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdFn)
    for ws in workspacePathMap:
        mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(ws["old"], ws["new"], False)
    mxd.saveACopy(newMxdFn)

updateDataSources(mxdFn, workspacePathMap, newMxdFn)
```

Comment: Is "mxdFn" the MXD which has all the layers? And should this be referenced using its full location r'C:\\\.mxd. Would it be possible to help me understand what you've written using an example of sorts.

Comment: @Zahir_Ibrahim - correct, `mxdFn` is the original MXD that you want to repath, `newMxdFn` is the copy that you save to.

Comment: @Zahir_Ibrahim - edited the code for clarification on usage.